# Can't exit i3 because no sensible terminal emulator is installed

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, i3

I am trying to setup Arch Linux, and after getting the most basic stuff setup I installed and ran i3 with:

```
pacman -S i3 dmenu xorg xorg-xinit
startx
```

It finally started, but I can't exit it. After pressing $mod+shift+E and confirming, it gives me the error:

```
i3-sensible-terminal could not find a terminal emulator. Please install one.
```

I also get this error from $mod+Enter. I'm confused because I can't exit back to the actual terminal in order to install a terminal emulator. Why does exiting i3 try to run a terminal emulator instead of closing dmenu/xorg and returning me to the actual(?) terminal? Can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/I3#Terminal_emulator

Comment: I understand this bit, but what's confusing me is how to get out of i3 into a shell so I can run the command to install a terminal emulator. And I'm also confused about why exiting i3 tries to run a terminal emulator instead of closing dmenu/xorg and returning me to the actual(?) terminal.

Comment: `Ctrl-Alt-F{2..6}` will get you to the console where you can install a terminal emulator.

Comment: @jasonwryan your comments would be a suitable answer.

Comment: Do you have any terminal installed or `i3-sensible-terminal` simply not detecting it?

Comment: I have the same issue. Ctrl-Alt-F{2..6} does nothing. Also resetting the VM to install xterm managed to brick unknown files so now i3 stalls at various stages before I have the chance to test whether the issue is fixed. Also trying to start the terminal in i3 now hangs for a minute or two before not showing anything after installing xterm. So I guess it's fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `i3` environment isn't usable in the case described because there's no way to get to a shell.  This is a graphical environment (X also known as X11) running in one of Linux's virtual consoles.  To switch to a text environment and get a shell, use <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd> together with a function-key for the number of the virtual console that you want to switch to.

Most X environments with Linux run in virtual console 7, some may be in virtual console 1.  So the quickest advice is to choose 2 through 6.

When you do this, you will get a login prompt.  This is expected.  You can be logged into the same machine several times.  Once logged in, you can run `pacman` to add whatever packages are needed, such as `xterm`.

Further reading:

- [Keyboard shortcuts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_shortcuts) (Arch wiki)
- [7. Console switching](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-7.html), The Keyboard and Console HOWTO
- [9.2.2. A Note About Virtual Consoles](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/sn-guimode-virtual-consoles-x86.html) (Red Hat)

Answer (score 5):

Do you have `xterm` installed?

`xterm` is the standard terminal emulator for the X Window System.

Install it with:

```
pacman -S xterm
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out above, either install `sensible terminal` or `xterm`, if you choose to use `xterm`  then you need to edit your `i3config` file accordingly.

When you've edited your config you need to refresh it by using `Mod + shift + R` for the changes to take effect. Then you should be all set.

**EDIT**

Of course you need to be able to use a terminal in the first place, @Thomas Dickey gave really good info on how to do that.