# Script variable to execute default terminal

Tags: bash, arch-linux, wine

How do I open the **default** terminal emulator in a bash script? For example I want my wine game to launch inside whatever terminal emulator is set as default, hence providing me with a debug interface.

My script goes as follows:

```
cd "/path/to/wine game's dir/
WINEPREFIX="/path/to/wine prefix" wine "/path/to/wine game's dir/exe"
```

I put all that in a .sh and to execute it i run `bash /path/to/script`

But like I said I'd like for it to launch a terminal window so i can see the output...

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you need the terminal. Does Wine require a graphical terminal (I've never used Wine)? If it's so you can see the output, then what about looking in the terminal where you launch the script?

Comment: You can view the game's debugging via the terminal and spot issues, i use straight up wine so i can make launchers for my games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There **is no** default terminal emulator.  If you attempt to invoke XTerm, and it is not installed, there is no default terminal emulator that gets run instead.  This is even more of a misnomer than "default shell" (for *login* shell set in the account database, *preferred* shell set in an environment variable, or supplier of `sh`).

There is the individual user's **preferred** terminal emulator, and (on some operating systems) a system-wide preferred terminal emulator.

## system-wide

The latter is set on Debian and derivative operating systems via its alternatives system, as `x-terminal-emulator`.  This command will invoke, and its manual page will be the manual page of, one of a number of (installed) GUI terminal emulator programs, amongst which the system administrator can switch with the command:

```
update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

On operating systems that have the i3 window manager available there is a similar, but not quite the same `i3-sensible-terminal` command, which attempts to look at the value of the (idiosyncratic) `TERMINAL` environment variable, run `x-terminal-emulator`, or one of a long hardwired list.  Compare (and contrast) this with Debian's `sensible-pager` and `sensible-editor` commands.

## per-user

The configuration of per-user preferred terminal emulators is a bit more complex.  It varies by desktop, and some of the system-wide preference mechanisms have per-user overrides.

- For the i3 window manager, `i3-sensible-terminal` actually is the desktop's way of starting the preferred terminal emulator, and its per-user configuration is an environment variable.
- For GNOME, there are settings in the GNOME settings database, read with:

  ```
  gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec
  gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg
  ```
- For KDE, it is a setting named `TerminalApplication` in the `kdeglobals` configuration file, read with:

  ```
  kreadconfig --file kdeglobals --group General --key TerminalApplication --default konsole
  ```

## GUI pagers

Of course, on the gripping hand *you don't need a terminal emulator*.  You could just as well use a pager program that has a GUI and a follow mode:

```
WINEPREFIX="/path/to/wine prefix" wine "/path/to/wine game's dir/exe" 2>&1 |
some-gui-text-viewer --follow -
```

Unfortunately, this is a bit of a gap in free software toolsets.

There are very few plain and simple GUI text file viewers.  The commonest suggestion that people make is to use a text file *editor* as a text file *viewer*, with tools like Kate, KWrite, or GVIM being given appropriate options or arguments telling them to treat their standard inputs as a text file to be edited.  `dtpad` had a `-viewOnly` option, similarly.

Dedicated text viewers that are not text editors do exist.  One *might* (I have not tried this.) also be able to bodge Mark Thomas Eriksen's `seetxt` into working as a filter by giving it `/dev/stdin` as the filename.  (And again, you might not.  It is a known difficulty for text file viewers to be unhappy when their input files are not seekable, as a pipe is not.  This tool might be one such.)  There are also tools such as Roland Baudin's `xfv` and KDE's `kless`.

But apparently none of these have an equivalent the abilities of TUI tools, such as `less`, to keep reading as more input arrives whilst allowing the user to view the existing text.

## Further reading

- [Can't exit i3 because no sensible terminal emulator is installed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/251456/5132)
- [What is the most portable method of launching a terminal emulator?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91642/5132)
- [What is the `editor` command in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77089/5132)
- [Command for the default in-terminal text editor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316856/5132)
- [Which systems have 'pager' shortcut/alias?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5383/5132)
- [Is there a graphical pager?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/269919/5132)
- [How to launch an application with default "terminal emulator" on Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32547/5132)
- http://seetxt.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

- XFCE through *exo-utils*:

  `exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator "bash -c '/path/to/script'"`

...or configure your script header with a sha-bang ( like `#!/bin/bash` ) e make it executable

`chmod +x '/path/to/script'` and you don’t need the `bash -c`:

```
exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator '/path/to/script'
```

- But with *x-terminal-emulator* you can use your default terminal options

(type `man  x-terminal-emulator`):

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "bash -c '/path/to/script'"
```

… or if it is executable with a *sha-bang*:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e '/path/to/script'
```

- Xterm itself (present in most linux distributions).
  You can even use its options to make it look different:

  `xterm -bg white -fg black -fa Monospace -fs 11 -iconic -geometry 60x10 -e bash -c '/path/to/script'`

or

```
xterm -bg white -fg black -fa Monospace -fs 11 -iconic -geometry 60x10 -e /path/to/script
```

-bg = background color

-fg = foreground (fonts) color

-fa = font name

-fs = font size

-iconic = minimized

-geometry = window size

-e program [ arguments ... ]  specifies the program and its command line arguments to be run in the xterm window